# How do I figure out a computer's architecture from the command line?

Tags: unix, command-line, cpu-architecture

Is there a standard program I can use to find out whether I'm on an i386 or x86, 32-bit or 64-bit machine? I'm on a Unix box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`uname -a`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uname&sektion=1)

Comment: `uname -m` would be closer, although I'm not sure if that's the whole story either.

Answer (score 0):

```
less /proc/cpuinfo
```

There should be more info there...